# Would there be working C debugger for Mac's Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

In order to find a solution I searched for "Mac Eclipse Debugger" on Google and this link was first on the list:

https://www.thomasvitale.com/how-to-setup-gdb-and-eclipse-to-debug-c-files-on-macos-sierra/

After following all the steps of installation and creation of certificate, I couldn't debug in C on Eclipse! I also tried some other links, they seem to be outdated as well. Would anyone know a working way to install a debugger?

Comment: More question for SuperUser

Comment: _"Last Update: 16 October 2018"_ doesn't sound outdated to me. Instead of asking if anyone knows it (the author of the linked article certainly knows it), tell us at which step you can't get any further.

Comment: @howlger. So I went through all the steps in the link confident it would work. It's when I tried to launch it and use it in Eclipse that I encountered "failed to launch gdb". It probably works, I'm just looking for confirmation from someone here or some other option to try.